# Deduplicate Oracle xmlagg list

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle 11.2 i'm trying to select 2 grouped lists from the tables below, here's my code:

```
CREATE  TABLE tmp_main AS (
  SELECT rownum col1, 'txt_' || to_char(rownum) Col2 FROM dual 
    CONNECT BY rownum<=2
);

CREATE TABLE tmp_keys AS (
  SELECT DECODE(rownum,1,1,2,1,3,1,4,2,5,2,6,2) col1, 'key_' || to_char(rownum) key1 , rownum seq FROM dual 
     CONNECT BY rownum<=6
);

CREATE TABLE tmp_line AS (
  SELECT DECODE(rownum,1,1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,2,6,2,7,2,8,2) col1, 'line_' || DECODE(rownum,2,1,3,1,4,2,5,3,7,3,8,4) line1 , rownum seq   FROM dual 
     CONNECT BY rownum<=8
);

update tmp_line set line1=null where line1='line_';
update tmp_keys set seq=null where col1=1;
```

tmp_keys.seq can be null so I need to order by seq first then key1
This is what i've tried:

```
SELECT  m.col1,m.col2,
RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,k.key1 , ',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY k.seq,k.key1 ).GetClobVal(),',') as key_list ,
RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,l.line1 || ',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY l.seq ).GetClobVal(),',')  line_list
FROM tmp_main m
JOIN tmp_keys k
ON m.col1=k.col1
JOIN tmp_line l
ON m.col1=l.col1
group by m.col1,col2;
```

Which gives:

```
col1 col2   key_list                                                                    line_list
1   txt_1   key_1,key_1,key_1,key_1,key_2,key_2,key_2,key_2,key_3,key_3,key_3,key_3     ,,,line_1,line_1,line_1,line_1,line_1,line_1,line_2,line_2,line_2
2   txt_2   key_4,key_4,key_4,key_4,key_5,key_5,key_5,key_5,key_6,key_6,key_6,key_6     line_3,line_3,line_3,,,,line_3,line_3,line_3,line_4,line_4,line_4
```

ie duplicates.

What I would like is:

```
col1 col2   key_list                    line_list
1   txt_1   key_1,key_2,key_3           ,line_1,line_1,line_2
2   txt_2   key_3,key_4,key_5           line_3,,line_3,line_4
```

ie null line1 values are kept.

Caveats:

- The real query is much bigger so 1 table scan would be nice as speed is important.
- The 2 lists could be > 4000 chars, so no listagg or similar functions allowed (which is  why i've used xmlagg and GetClobVal())

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, assign a `row_number` for the key and line values, starting at 1 for each key or line `seq`.

So you'll `partition by` the final grouping values and the relevant seq. Then sort by the key/line values:

```
row_number() over ( 
  partition by m.col1,col2,k.seq
  order by key1
) rnk, 
row_number() over ( 
  partition by m.col1,col2,l.seq
  order by line1
) rnl
```

Then aggregate only those rows where this row number = 1:

```
with rws as (
  select 
    m.*, line1, key1,
    l.seq seql,k.seq seqk,
    row_number() over ( 
      partition by m.col1,col2,k.seq
      order by key1
    ) rnk, 
    row_number() over ( 
      partition by m.col1,col2,l.seq
      order by line1
    ) rnl
  from tmp_main m
  join tmp_keys k
  on   m.col1=k.col1
  join tmp_line l
  on   m.col1=l.col1
)
  select 
    col1,col2,
    rtrim(
      xmlagg(
        xmlelement(
          e,
          case when rnk = 1 then key1 || ',' end 
        ).extract('//text()') 
        order by seqk
      ).getclobval(),','
    ) key_list ,
    rtrim(
      xmlagg(
        xmlelement(
          e,
          case when rnl = 1 then line1 || ',' end 
        ).extract('//text()') 
        order by seql 
      ).getclobval(),','
    ) line_list
  from   rws
  group  by col1,col2;

COL1    COL2     KEY_LIST             LINE_LIST               
      1 txt_1    key_1,key_2,key_3    ,line_1,line_1,line_2    
      2 txt_2    key_4,key_5,key_6    line_3,,line_3,line_4
```

Comment: @Chris_Saxon Thanks a lot, works well. I'll try this on the real query and report back.

Comment: @chris_saxon I just found out that tmp_keys.seq can be null.  So, if I run : update tmp_keys set seq=null; Do you know how I can change your query to order by seq ,key1 to make it work, as key_list now only contains 1 value.

Comment: So you have just rn = 1 for each group? You'll need to find some other attribute in your data you can use to partition the values. What's the other value that is different for the two `line_1` values you want to report the `line_list`? (if the answer is "nothing", you're stuck!)

Answer (score 1):

Deduplicate and the aggregate the rows before joining the tables:

```sql
SELECT  m.col1,
        m.col2,
        SUBSTR( k.key_list, 1, LENGTH( k.key_list ) - 1 ) AS key_list,
        SUBSTR( l.line_list, 1, LENGTH( l.line_list ) - 1 ) AS line_list
FROM    tmp_main m
        JOIN (
          SELECT col1,
                 XMLAGG(
                   XMLELEMENT(E,key1 , ',').EXTRACT('//text()')
                   ORDER BY seq
                 ).GetClobVal() as key_list
          FROM   (
            SELECT k.*,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY col1, key1 ORDER BY seq ) AS rn
            FROM   tmp_keys k
          )
          WHERE  rn = 1
          GROUP BY col1
        ) k
        ON m.col1=k.col1
        JOIN (
          SELECT col1,
                 XMLAGG(
                   XMLELEMENT(E,line1 , ',').EXTRACT('//text()')
                   ORDER BY seq
                 ).GetClobVal() as line_list
          FROM   (
            SELECT l.*,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY col1, line1 ORDER BY seq ) AS rn
            FROM   tmp_line l
          )
          WHERE  rn = 1
          GROUP BY col1
        ) l
        ON m.col1=l.col1;
```

Also, don't use `RTRIM` when you are expecting to have empty strings between delimiters in your list as if this empty string occurs as the terminal element of the list then it will be stripped out by `RTRIM`; instead, just remove the last delimiter.

Outputs:

> ```
> COL1 | COL2  | KEY_LIST          | LINE_LIST     
> ---: | :---- | :---------------- | :-------------
>    1 | txt_1 | key_1,key_2,key_3 | ,line_1,line_2
>    2 | txt_2 | key_4,key_5,key_6 | line_3,,line_4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ee5b9375a9e8b5f7c2efd136be1b5ec1)*

Comment: I did think of this type of idea but it got very complex and I gave up. Thanks a lot for working it through. I'll try both your and chris's solution and see which runs fastest on the real query (and is easiest to expand for more colomns)  and report back

Answer (score 0):

In the real query the tables are much larger and I needed to add a predicate:

```
Where m.another_col='xxx'
```

When I added  this predicate (after the last line) to the solution from @MT0 I got "No space left on device", I suspect it was because the inline queries ran first on the whole tmp_keys and tmp_line tables and too many rows were selected before the predicate ran. 
I therefore went with the solution provided by @chris_saxon, with the new predicate added to the end of the WITH subquery factor , after changing:

```
 row_number() over (  partition by m.col1,col2,k.seq order by key1 ) rnk
```

to :

```
row_number() over (  partition by m.col1,col2,key1 order by k.seq,key1 ) rnk
```

to solve the problem with k.seq possibly being null.